# Where is the official Direct Connect (DC) protocol connection documentation located?

Tags: protocols, p2p

I want to create my own client for the Direct Connect protocol. But I am unable to find any documentation/ resource on how I can connect to a DC hub ( server ) using basic network requests, and other actions related to DC

I tried searching at these places:

```
http://wiki.ptokax.org/
http://www.dslreports.com/faq/dc
https://www.dcbase.org
```

I also tried sniffing the requests on the DC hub IP addresses using WireShark, but still couldn't figure out.

Comment: The wikipedia page suggests that there's differences depending on the servers/versions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Connect_(protocol)#Protocol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best documentation on **Direct Connect** protocols you can find today are these two detailed manuals written by **Fredrik Ullner**:

- [NMDC Protocol](https://nmdc.sourceforge.io/NMDC.html) (first version, most popular)
- [ADC Protocol](https://adc.sourceforge.io/ADC.html) (next version, less popular)

These are the official protocol specifications by the way.

Out of interest: Which OS are you writing the client software for?